# copy row to another section in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with with some sections and each section with some rows.Every row has a favorite button.If the button is clicked the row should get added to the favourites section.
(which is initially empty).

I have written some code.but the problem is it is working in iOS 5 simulator and getting crashed  in iOS 6 simulator with Invalid tableView update error.

Can someone tell me where the problem is.?

```
-(void)moveRowToFavourites:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:favouritesArray.count inSection:0]];
    [favouritesArray insertObject:cell.textLabel.text atIndex:favouritesArray.count];
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)tempArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

**EDIT**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(searching){
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else{
        if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
            if(section == 0){
                return favouritesArray.count;
            }else{
                NSString* key = [self.proCategoriesArray objectAtIndex:section - 1];
                NSArray *aArray = [sectionContentDict valueForKey:key];
                return aArray.count;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error description contains a very clear explanation of the problem.

Comment: did ou try reloadData instead of updates?

Comment: move a row means you have to insert into favorites array also you have to delete from temp array and do the same in table sections

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update' is the error

Comment: it means you are defining 0 rows to section in method numberofrowinsection in which you want to insert that row

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your data source is returning 0 as number of sections and rows. You are not correctly inserting/deleting rows, when you insert a new row, data source methods get called again, and if for instance you try to insert an object in a way that the row count will be 4, and data source `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns 3, you get an exception because you're trying yo add more objects that what data source promises.

When you try to update a table view all these data source methods get called again:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath;
```

You must ensure that they return correct values. I suspect that you aren't even implementing them.

**Edit**

The problem is that you are just inserting a new object in `favouritesArray`, but this doesn't affect the number of rows returned by `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. There you aren't returning `favouritesArray.count`, the exception is due to the fact that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns a lower number than the rows that the table view should have.

In your case I think that you don't even need to call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`, you can do everything with your data source:

```
-(void)moveRowToFavourites:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
    [favouritesArray insertObject:cell.textLabel.text atIndex:favouritesArray.count];
    [[self tableView]reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return favouritesArray.count;
}
```

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you should return a cell that has an object fetched form `favouritesArray` as text.

Comment: yes,that is where the error is.but everything seems to be fine and working in iOS5 simulator and am getting this error in iOS6 and above simulators

Comment: @ChandraSekhar May I see the data source methods? I'm pretty sure the error is there.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Got the problem, you are trying to insert a new row in the table view, while `tableView:numberOrRowsInSection:` returns the same identical value as before. I suggest to ignore `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` and to just rely on data source. In the edit you should see a way to make it work (maybe you'll need to modify this code if this isn't exactly what you need, but I hope it gives an idea of how to fix the problem).

Comment: the same problem again.its not working in iOS6 simulator.the only good news is there is no crash this time.

Comment: It doesn't work? How? Do you see an empty table view or what? describe it better please. Maybe `favouritesArray` is `nil`? If you add the full code it may help to recognize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just should call the following:

```
[favouritesArray addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
[tableView reloadData];
```

Make sure you implemented this function:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch(section){
         case 0:
            return favouritesArray.count;
         //Your other sections have to placed here, too
         default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Then your tableView should update itself. The problem is that you insert whole cells, but you just have to insert data in your array. Hope it helps!